# spring webflux with keycloak authentication over netty server

Tags: reactive-programming, keycloak, netty, spring-webflux

i want to run webflux based web app using non blocking netty server and authentication using keycloak.
seems like keycloak does not support netty server. is there a way to override default behavior of keycloak and use netty instead of tomcat?
this is required becuase my webflux application does not work properly on other web servers.

i want to use keycloak for basic authentication but when i configure keycloak in my application and try to run it it does not come up on netty dependecies, only when i add tomcat to my webflux pom.xml then keycloak server comes up.
and idea how ot run keycloak on netty server?

Comment: Afaik Keycloak is a red hat product running on jboss wildfly if im not misstaken. Not tomcat.